# After scanning a QR Code how to open another activity along wtih QR data passed?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a school project QR scanner to just get the text out of the QR code and display it over the next activity. But it just crashed when I use intent but works when it's just display on the scanner activity. ( T .T)

Scan.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        scannerView.stopCamera();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result){
        String something = result.getText();
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, Result.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", something);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        finish();
    }
```

Result.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        output =  findViewById(R.id.Result);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode==0){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                output.setText(contents);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename your Result activity to ResultActivity. I think the issue here is that scanner output class name is Result and your next activity name is also Result so it confuses the app.

Comment: Bro... I tried your solution and I can't believe its so simple yet it worked! it took me a while as I had to come up with a second backup project for the present day but thank you~! 
( ^ .^)
I still can't believe how it was just caused by a class name

Comment: Happy to help bro. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your Result.java class in AndroidManifest ?
Do post your crash log here.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android. Declare what exactly? Is this the declaration you mean? `<activity android:name=".Result"></activity>`
And here's my crash log
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tvziqsjs3pni63niuxr03/Error-Log.docx?dl=0&rlkey=8cp3iuvn4xah2c31x75xk5vda)

Comment: Yes. Please do that. In your AndroidManifest.java class

Comment: @ReMiKURH You have not added you activity in AndroidManifest. Update it

Comment: Oh I see then I did declared `<activity android:name=".Result"></activity>` in the AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand flow of starting an activity for result, check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

For you issue you have start Result.java activity, in it's onCreate() method start Scan.java

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (this, Scan.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

No in Scan.java handle scan result and pass it to Scan.java

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result){
    String something = result.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent ();
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", something);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
```

in Scan.java in onActivityResult() will handle the resule

Comment: I tried your solution but the error log shows [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/y99aowzozysaqr1sptlfo/Error-Log-2.docx?dl=0&rlkey=mqc8i3hgvvsr09tnkctywx936) which points to `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in Result.java. You must access your data `SCAN_RESULT` in `onCreate` only

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    output =  findViewById(R.id.Result);
    String contents = getIntent().getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            output.setText(contents);

}
```

When you use `startActivityForResult` in Scan.java; your `onActivityResult` must be in same activity. And there is no meaning of `onActivityResult` in Result.java

Comment: I tried your solution but the Logcat is saying `at Project.AP02.Scan.handleResult(Scan.java:66)` which is in my Scan.java